# Get overall smallest elements' distribution in dataframe with sorted columns more efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with sorted columns, something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({q: np.sort(np.random.randn(10).round(2)) for q in ['blue', 'green', 'red']})
       blue  green   red
    0 -2.15  -0.76 -2.62
    1 -0.88  -0.62 -1.65
    2 -0.77  -0.55 -1.51
    3 -0.73  -0.17 -1.14
    4 -0.06  -0.16 -0.75
    5 -0.03   0.05 -0.08
    6  0.06   0.38  0.37
    7  0.41   0.76  1.04
    8  0.56   0.89  1.16
    9  0.97   2.94  1.79
```

What I want to know is how many of the *n* smallest elements in the whole frame are in each column. This is the only thing I came up with:

```
is_small = df.isin(np.partition(df.values.flatten(), n)[:n])
```

with n=10 it looks like this:

```
        blue  green    red
    0   True   True   True
    1   True  False   True
    2   True  False   True
    3   True  False   True
    4  False  False   True
    5  False  False  False
    6  False  False  False
    7  False  False  False
    8  False  False  False
    9  False  False  False
```

Then by applying np.sum I get the number corresponding to each column.

I'm dissatisfied with this solution because it in no way utilizes the sortedness of the original data. **All** the data gets partitioned and **all** the data is then checked for whether it's in the partition. It seems wasteful, and I can't seem to figure out a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you can compare the largest of n-smallest values against the partitioned one and then use `idxmin` to leverage the sorted nature -

```
# Find largest of n smallest numbers
N = (np.partition(df.values.flatten(), n)[:n]).max()
out = (df<=N).idxmin(axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [152]: np.random.seed(0)

In [153]: df = pd.DataFrame({q: np.sort(np.random.randn(10).round(2)) \
          for q in ['blue', 'green', 'red']})

In [154]: df
Out[154]: 
   blue  green   red
0 -0.98  -0.85 -2.55
1 -0.15  -0.21 -1.45
2 -0.10   0.12 -0.74
3  0.40   0.14 -0.19
4  0.41   0.31  0.05
5  0.95   0.33  0.65
6  0.98   0.44  0.86
7  1.76   0.76  1.47
8  1.87   1.45  1.53
9  2.24   1.49  2.27

In [198]: n = 5

In [199]: N = (np.partition(df.values.flatten(), n)[:n]).max()

In [200]: (df<=N).idxmin(axis=0)
Out[200]: 
blue     1
green    1
red      3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: There appears to be a problem with this: for example with the same data and n=5 its results are 1, 0, 2, while their sum should be 5

Comment: Pretty sure it works with `(df<np.partition(df.values.flatten(), n)[n]).idxmin(axis=0)`  though

Comment: @MegaBluejay The issue was with `np.partition` not giving in sorted order, so we need to sort the smallest partition and then proceed. Fixed. Sort or finding max that is.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say, you are looking at 10 smallest, you can stack and find value_count for the 10 smallest

```
df.stack().nsmallest(10).index.get_level_values(1).value_counts()
```

You get

```
red      5
blue     4
green    1
```